# Surround certain string with specified characters using regex-capable editor

Tags: vim, notepad++, regex, sed, string-manipulation

I need to  format certain string in Sphinx's documentation **H2** Header.

**Example**:

`v-add-user` should be replaced with

`*********
 v-add-user
 *********`

I search for needed string in Notepad++ (regex `^(v-.*)`) and replace it with

`********$0********`

in order to achieve the desired.

Current solution is pretty gruesome.
Is there any way to optimize and simplify current solution or get another one, using Notepad++, sed, vim or any kind of software capable to perform such conversion?
It also would be great if number of asterisks in the string-wrapper corresponds to the length of string being wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any compact solution, so I prefer to use *sed* to process sources.

I treat all of the matched strings with the following command.

`sed -ri 's/^(v-.*)$/******\n\1\n******/' output.rst`

It satisfies my needs for now.